# Calcuation Result Always 0

Tags: c#, calculation

I'm trying to write a very simple program to calculate liquid nicotine strengh. Basically it's `(strengh / nicStrengh) * amount`. And it always comes out as `0`.

```
private void lblCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int strengh = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxDesiredStrengh.Text);
    int nicStrengh = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxNicStrengh.Text);
    int amount = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxAmount.Text);

    int result = strengh / nicStrengh * amount;

    string resultStr = result.ToString();

    label1.Text = resultStr;
}
```

Comment: `strengh / nicStrengh` - *integer division* - put it as `amount * strengh / nicStrengh`;

Comment: Try to use `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: Integer division will not round, it will always truncate. Thus any absolute fraction smaller than 1 is always 0.

Answer (score 3):

When you divide *integer* to *integer* the result is *integer* as well; e.g.

```
 5 / 10 == 0       // not 0.5 - integer division
 5.0 / 10.0 == 0.5 // floating point division
```

In your case `strengh < amount` that's why `strengh / amount == 0`. If you want `result` being `int` (say `3`) put it as

```
  int result = strengh * amount / nicStrengh;
```

if you want `double result` (i.e. *floating point* value, say `3.15`) let system know that you want floating point arithmetics:

```
  double result = (double)strengh / nicStrengh * amount;
```

Comment: Or change `Convert.ToInt32()` to `Convert.ToDouble()` and any `int` to `double` to get floating point values all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int s = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int n = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int a = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        int result = (s / n) * a;
        label1.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```

or this if result is with comma

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double s = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        double n = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        double a = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        double result = (s / n) * a;
        label1.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```